# Максимальное заполнение внешнего контейнера компоновки с помощью UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача заполнить контейнер (Grid, например) максимально эффективно по площади элементами типа Image. Максимальная эффективность - значит соотношение площади контейнера к суммарной площади элементов будет максимальным (в идеале 1, но в рамках этой задачи так не обязательно получится). Количество изображений неизвестно заранее. Изображения не должны менять свое соотношение сторон. При этом они должны растягиваться и размещаться по строкам и колонкам так, чтобы максимально заполнять внешний контейнер. Внешний контейнер динамически растягивается в соответствии с размерами окна.

Я пытался использовать стандартные свойства UniformGrid (и WrapPanel), но у меня не получилось ничего хорошего.

Например, UniformGrid если свойства Rows и Columns не задавать явно, рассчитывает количество колонок и строк сам. Так для 1 элемента будет 1 строка, для 2-4 - две строки, для 5-9 элементов -  три строки и т.д. Размер внешнего контейнера при этом не учитывается.

То что нужно:
[image: То что хотелось получить]
То что получается:
[image: То что получилось]

Еще раз, желаемый результат (сделан с помощью дополнительного класса, а не разметки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** а в WPF вообще есть стандартные средства разметки xaml, чтобы организовать заполнение контейнера компоновки так, как описано в задаче? Или это задача двумерной упаковки, для которой нужно писать костыли в виде каких-нибудь конвертеров данных?

Comment: надо в одну все строку? или как?

Comment: Эм... нет. Надо чтобы соотношение площади контейнера к суммарной площади элементов будет максимальным.  Я Наверное еще одну картинку прикреплю, чтобы показать другой случай.

Comment: Как оно одлжно выглядеть, если картинок например 5? Что будет, если у картинок разное соотношение сторон?

Comment: Я подгрузил гифку - думаю теперь яснее будет задача. По поводу разного соотношения сторон - пока решения не принял, думаю нужно сделать чтобы либо по горизонтали либо по вертикали они все были равными. Но это я потом на будущее буду разбираться.

Comment: В чем смысл задачи? Вижу, что вы что-то пытаетесь изобрести, но пока не понял, что. Проблем с написанием кода нет. А вот с понятием, как это должно работать есть. [Это оно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)? Зачем это вам нужно? Очевидно, что стандартного решения этой задачи нет. Ну потому что от нее практической пользы почти никогда нет, нужно писать свое решение.

Comment: При одинаковом размере и заданном соотношении длина/ширина это НЕ задача упаковки. Однако, судя по гифке, алгоритм расчёта у вас уже есть, и хочется только не самому рассчитывать оптимальное расположение, а использовать решения встроенными средствами wpf/xaml "из коробки", так?

Comment: Да, возможно Вы правы, что это не вполне стандартная вещь. И да, это фактически частный случай задачи упаковки. По поводу практической пользы спорить не буду. Практический смысл такой: в эти Image'ы приходят изображения от камер. Нужно размещать их в окне desktop-приложения так, чтобы площадь окна использовалась максимально эффективно и чтобы они были видны все одновременно.  Проблем написать дополнительный конвертер данных действительно никаких нет (по сути я его уже написал), но я хотел убедиться, что не существует стандартных средств xaml-разметки, чтобы реализовать это.

Comment: @MBo  Совершенно верно, хочется решить встроенными средствами. По поводу задача упаковки это или нет - не буду спорить, возможно Вам виднее.

Comment: @andreyLv В задаче упаковки - фиксированный размер предметов.

Comment: Тогда ваша задача сводится к "черновой" разметке экрана. И позволить пользователю управлять размером прямоугольников так, чтобы ему было удобно наблюдать. Например я хочу одну камеру больше сделать в 2 раза, чем остальные. Оптимальное заполнение площади может в принципе не устраивать пользователя.

Comment: @aepot Для начала мне нужно решить вариант с оптимальным заполнением площади - как один из базовых вариантов компоновки. А затем уже буду работать с изменением размера каждого прямоугольника по желанию пользователя.

Comment: Для решения задачи оптимального заполнения вы не определились с допущениями. Можно ли кропать отображаемые прямоугольники, то есть менять их соотношение сторон. Можно ли менять компоновку прямоугольников на экране, если пользователь изменил размер или соотношение сторон окна. Например, я сделал 2+3, потом случайно поресайзил онкно и оно поломалось, и назад чтобы вернуть надо заново расставлять кадры. Мне кажется, в текущей ситуации вам хватит стандартного поведения WrapPanel с конвертером, который размер ячейки подстроит так, чтобы все влезало. Ожидаемое поведение неочевидно.

Comment: Нашел пример интерфейса http://camera.avk-wellcom.ru/data/textimages/vvedenie/cce0c2acf422f4831341893e58ed2d38.png обратите внимание на синие кнопочки под рабочей областью. Быть может он натолкнет на кое-какие идеи. Основное опасение в том, что использование тайлов строго одинакового размера даже для стандартной разметки - может оказаться неудачным решением.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за помощь. Я эти проблемы тоже понимаю. )